# How do I pass all the output of process to a function?

Tags: process, subprocess

I want to call a command asynchronously, and define a function that handles output from that command. I don't want to simply write output to a buffer.

According to the Elisp info (36.9.2 Process Filter Functions) I need to set a process filter function. I tried this:

```
(defun my-echo-filter (proc string)
  (message "proc: %s string: %s" proc string))

(let ((my-proc (start-file-process "foo" nil "date")))
  (set-process-filter my-proc #'my-echo-filter)) ; writes the time to *Messages*
```

However, this makes me nervous. I'm starting the process first, and only afterwards am I attaching the process filter.

If I do anything between creating the process and attaching the process filter, I can miss output.

```
(let ((my-proc (start-file-process "foo" nil "date")))
  (sleep-for 2)
  (set-process-filter my-proc #'my-echo-filter)) ; Does not write the time!
```

How do I create a process and ensure that my process filter doesn't miss anything?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I think this is a non-issue.  Emacs is single-threaded, and only processes output from subprocesses when idle.  There's no time in between calling `start-file-process` and `set-process-filter` when process output could arrive behind your back (as it were).  You would have to call `sit-for` or `accept-process-output` for that to happen.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Presumably `sleep-for` counts as idle. What about if garbage collection occurs?

Comment: It seems very unlikely to me that GC would trigger anything related to subprocesses -- AFAIK there's very little that can safely be handled during GC -- but you would have to ask someone more expert for a definitive answer.

Comment: BTW, the relevant line is in `(elisp) Accepting Output`: "Output from asynchronous subprocesses normally arrives only while Emacs is waiting for some sort of external event, such as elapsed time or terminal input."

Comment: @JonO. would you like to make your comments an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I understand it, this is a non-issue.  Emacs is single-threaded, and only processes output from subprocesses when idle.  Therefore, there is no time between calling `start-file-process` and `set-process-filter` when process output could arrive without being handled.

The info page `(elisp) Accepting Output` states:

> Output from asynchronous subprocesses normally arrives only while Emacs is waiting for some sort of external event, such as elapsed time or terminal input.

For this to become a problem, you would have to separate creating the process and setting the filter function with a call to `sit-for`, `accept-process-output`, or some other command that involves user interaction via the event loop.